# Fullscreen Rotating Background Image

Tags: java, android, animation, bitmap, imageview

Developing an app for Android and I'm required to have a fullscreen image rotate (spin around infinitely, pivoted at the centre of the screen) in the background.

I have tried rotating the ImageView using RotateAnimation which works well, except the image is cropped to the size of the parent view.

I have also tried expanding the parent view to a set size (750dp) but it doesn't work well across all the different screen sizes.

Does anyone know of an easy way to implement this, which would involve scaling to uniformly fit the screen size?

Cheers,
Dylan

Screenshot of the image:

[image]

Comment: any solution regarding this question ?